# Kohana vs Yii vs ...? Какой фреймворк способен максимально эффективно использовать ресурсы сервера?

Tags: php, yii, zend-framework, kohana, symfony2

Нужны практические сравнительные характеристики фреймворков Kohana, Yii и т.д. Например, в виде графиков. В кохане ORM  вызывает большие вопросы производительности с ростом посещаемости. Так же фигня с поисками по папкам. Ищем класс сначала в апликэйшен потом в сустем, потом по подпапкам и т.д. Думается, что эта бодяга тоже будет как то сказываться на производительности. Кэширование тоже нужно и грамотное, чтоб память не забивало.

Пока сам копаю, изучаю, смотрю, думаю. Но пока прихожу к выводу что самопис лучше без всяких там ORM  а тупо запросы SELECT* FROM без всякой заумной бодяги. Более того, мое мышление строится на том как из сервера выжать все. Поэтому часть функционала будет на Node.js. Я уверен что среди вас уже есть те кто с этим разбирался и выбрал лучшее.

Собственно к вам и вопрос: что выбрали и почему?

Comment: > Более того мое мышление строится на том как из сервера выжать все. Поэтому часть функционала будет на Node.js

как-то бессмысленно, хотите скорости - c++  причем не частично, а полностью, ну а если хотите удобства, то node, тока непонятно зачем вам часть на php, только и будете делать что устраивать между ними коммуникацию.

> Но пока прихожу к выводу что самопис лучше без всяких там ORM а тупо запросы SELECT* FROM без всякой заумной бодяги.

плохой вывод, обычно приводящий к провалу проекта.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, в целом, в вопросе не рассматривается одна сторона, которая, на мой взгляд, имеет очень важное значение - поддержка существующего проекта. Тут даже Этвуд недавно поднимал свой [пост](http://blog.codinghorror.com/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive/) по поводу того, что серваки в проекте - это самое дешевое.

> Но пока прихожу к выводу что самопис лучше без всяких там ORM

Возможность выполнить запрос "напрямую" у вас будет в любом фреймворке, причем затраты на подключение могут быть крайне малы (никто не говорит, что надо запускать все роутеры и свистелки фреймворка). Более того, ни один нормальный фреймворк не полезет ничего выполнять и подключать (кроме класса ядра), пока его об этом не попросят. Самопис же обрекает вас на страдание, в результате которого вы перепишите половину Yii.

> Ищем класс сначала в апликэйшен потом в сустем, потом по подпапкам и т.д.
>
> Думается что эта бодяга тоже будет как то сказываться на производительности.

Да, конечно, эта бодяга будет тратить процессорное время и раскручивать лишний раз диск. Но, во-первых, на сколько процентов можно ускорить приложение за счет замены этого failsafe-механизма на банальный хардкорный инклюд, во-вторых, сколько багов вызовет смена этих инклюдов по той или иной причине, и, наконец, есть схемы (привет, PSR), которые точно знают расположение класса. Я уж молчу о том, что можно при каждом запросе обновлять хранящийся где угодно class map, что тоже позволит выйти на "точно знаю где" уровень.
ORM- и AR-системы тоже не просто так появились. Да, иногда они являются самой тормознутой частью приложения, но нормальную event-систему без них не построишь? Да и вообще они значительно сокращают время разработки.

> Я уверен что среди вас уже есть те кто с этим разбирался и выбрал лучшее.

Symfony, хоть я до сих пор и сижу на мануалах. Это самое бескостыльное и гибкое решение, которое может быть, пусть и расширяется она через тонну добавочного кода. Да, энтерпрайз, да, жрет много, да, визитку на ней делать бессмысленно. Но все до мелочей сделано по лучшим принципам проектирования.
Если отталкиваться только от скорости, то у PHP самый лучший выбор - это наверняка Phalcon.

P.S.

> Поэтому часть функционала будет на Node.js

очень большой риск упереться в то, что поддержка и перепись уже написанного, переваяние апи будут отхватывать добротную часть времени разработки.

P.P.S. Ну и еще про человеческий фактор. Человек, ориентирующийся в фреймворке, быстрее заоптимизирует какой-то кусок кода, чем человек, который взял самый быстрый фреймворк, но при встрече с неоптимизированным куском не знает, с чего начать.

Comment: node.js по-моему хорош как точка входа для вебсокетов например. Если вообще возникла нужда ставить node, то я бы его делал чисто точкой входа, потом сервер очередей и дальше php.
Программировать все приложение на node, нихочу никого задеть, но это пипец. Мне очень сложно писать код в системе, где удобство стоит настолько ниже производительности что прям вообще...

Comment: @donkey вы просто не умеете его готовить, node гораздо удобнее php, особенно если использовать какой-нибудь фреймворк.

Answer (score 1):

ORM и производительность вещи совместимые конечно, но осторожно. При неосторожном использовании любой фреймворк начнет строить трехэтажные запросы.

С внутренней производительностью у всех нормально, просто потому что она не сравнится со временем запросов к БД.

Я использую Zend Framework, ORM так как такового и нету. В смысле там есть модели, можно построить необходимый уровень абстракции работы с данными,  но конструктор запросов обычный PDO. В ZF2 вроде есть ActiveRecord но почему то все используют Doctrine.

Мне лично оно и не надо ибо я уже давно перешел на noSQL, на кой черт спрашивается нужен SQL если джоины и те под запретом в хайлоаде. Минусы реляционной бд перекрывают ее плюсы при такой постановке вопроса.

Чисто по производительности одним из самых быстрых считается Yii, но еще раз - фреймворк у вас очень врядли будет узким местом, БД будет

Comment: > С внутренней производительностью у всех нормально, просто потому что она не сравнится со временем запросов к БД.

Я бы все-таки возразил. В общем случае без подробностей - да, но сейчас есть и кэширование, и, наконец-то, ssd, поэтому в сайте, который ворочает не миллионами записей, горло вполне может оказаться в самом приложении.

Comment: @Etki Да, но оно в любом случае будет связано с неэффективностью использования БД, кеша.